# How is set php function if true =1 & else false =0 in 4 var

Tags: php, function, variables

my function is not worked.

```
    $displayon = "display:none !important";
    $displayoff = "padding:0";

    $displayres = "responsive";
    $displayres1 = "responsive1";

   function displays($check)
   {
    if ($display1 OR $display2 OR $display3 OR $display4 == $displayon){
       echo $displayres1;
       return true;
    }
    else  {
        echo $displayres;
    }

   }
```

and

```
<div class="<?php if (displays($check) == true){echo $check;};?>"style="<?php echo $display1;?>">
<div class="<?php if (displays($check) == true){echo $check;};?>"style="<?php echo $display2;?>">
<div class="<?php if (displays($check) == true){echo $check;};?>"style="<?php echo $display3;?>">
<div class="<?php if (displays($check) == true){echo $check;};?>"style="<?php echo $display4;?>">
```

But not worked.
I want if "$display1 or $display2 or ..." was equal to **"$displayon"** , Use **responsive1**. Otherwise, use responsive.
I have a photo gallery of 4 columns.
 In the module, you can disable each column. 
I want the responsive to become 3 columns if a column is disabled.
 And if two columns are disabled, responsive becomes 2 columns.
 Each display (display1,2,3,4) represents a column.

Comment: WOW! Scope issues and non existing variables and invalid IF syntax. Not sure where to start, or whether its even worth starting

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and see what it tells you

Comment: What is `$checks` and why are you passing it to your function as a parameter BUT NOT USING IT in the function

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the function needs to do this:

```
function displays($check) {
    if ($check == "display:none !important") {
        return 'responsive1';
    } else {
        return 'responsive';
    }
}
```

And be used like this:

```
<div class="<?php echo displays($display1); ?>"style="<?php echo $display1;?>">
<div class="<?php echo displays($display2); ?>"style="<?php echo $display2;?>">
<div class="<?php echo displays($display3); ?>"style="<?php echo $display3;?>">
<div class="<?php echo displays($display4); ?>"style="<?php echo $display4;?>">
```

You pass the style string as the argument to the `displays` function, and return one class or the other depending on whether or not it matches the specific string you're looking for.

---

Some important things to note:

- you can't use a variable in a function if it's defined outside the function. (See [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php))
- You can't compare multiple things to one thing like this

  ```
  if ($display1 OR $display2 OR $display3 OR $display4 == $displayon){
  ```

  Instead you'll need to do them one at a time like

  ```
  if ($display1 == $displayon || $display2 == $displayon ... etc.
  ```

  Or put them in an array and use `in_array`. But I don't think that's what you were going for here anyway.
- When you define a function like `function displays($check)`, the `$check` is a parameter, and when the function is executed it will take the value of whatever you put there when you call the function. For example if we say `displays('hi');` then `$check` will have the string `'hi'`. And if we say `$someVar = 42;` and call `displays($someVar);` then `$check` will have the value `42`.

Comment: Wow thats a leap in the dark :) I hope you are right :) :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought the question was kind of like one of those pictures that if you stare at it long enough the hidden image comes into focus. Maybe just wishful thinking

Comment: I can only see a Dolphin :)

Comment: I have a photo gallery of 4 columns.
In the module, you can disable each column.
I want the responsive to become 3 columns if a column is disabled.
And if two columns are disabled, responsive becomes 2 columns.
Each display (display1,2,3,4) represents a column.